# Jqgrid Ajax Success Result

Tags: jqgrid

I'm searching for variable name of Jqgrid Ajax Success Result bcoz I added additional data for further processing.

I'm talking about result of the `url:` I know this is jusing ajax call, but i dont know how jqgrid name its result, for example, `sucess: function(result)`

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
url:'server.php?q=2',
datatype: "json",
```

Anyone knows whats the result name?

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636580/how-can-i-get-jqgrid-to-recognize-server-sent-errors) there are some good examples about catching error codes in the result of the Ajax call by defining a loadError function ( [demo here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), under "New in version 3.2" -> Controling server errors ), and looking at the data that was returned (when there is no error) by adding a loadComplete function.